# Changing Control Plane Load balancer address

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

We need to change the controlePlaneEndpoint of the k8s HA cluster as the LB Machine need to be replaced.

We have setuped k8s HA cluster last year on prem with a load balancer machine in front of the cluster by using kubeadm with config file like described here https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#steps-for-the-first-control-plane-node

The cluster should use another load balancer as endpoint and not the former one.

Comment: Which kubernetes version you are using? `kubelet --version`

Comment: We have v1.12.2 as Version